# hold the execution when popup window is open - javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to open a window (a spring web application) from another web application (a java servlet based web application).
Both are deployed in same server (say JBoss).

My requirement is in a JavaScript function, I have to open the window and the execution has to wait till the window is closed. This is because I will return something on success(or If user closes the window) and the further execution carries on this return value.

```
//some statements...
var win = window.open("http://localhost/webapp/");
```

I am trying this below code. But popup window is waiting for the while loop to end and not displaying the page. Force closing the window also doesn't help.

```
while(!win.closed){}
//some statements...
```

I tried..

```
var windowOpened = true;
var timer = setInterval(function(){
if(win.closed){windowOpened = false; clearInterval(timer);}
}, 500);
while(windowOpened){}
//statements that need to run after window closed...
```

no use...Used recursive functions.. still same issue..

I can split up the code say

```
var timer = setInterval(function(){
if(win.closed){
clearInterval(timer);
//statements that need to run after window closed...
}
}, 500);
```

but I want to know if there is a possibility or not. 
I am extending an already existing process and this may save duplication of codes.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parent js code

```
<script>
    var myexecution = 1;
    var callbackreceived = false;
    console.log(myexecution);
    //function to execute from child
    function myFunc() {
        callbackreceived = true;
        alert('Continue your process')
    }
    window.open("http://localhost:54954/child.html");       

</script>
```

Child js ccode

```
    var RunParentFunction = function () {
        window.parent.myFunc();
    }; window.onbeforeunload = function () { RunParentFunction(); }
```

---

You can use `parent.myFunc`  to call it

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. 
Is that win.onload or win.onunload

Comment: its `win.onload`

Comment: You can modify it as per your requirements

Comment: Same issue. page in child window in not opening. I think it is waiting for do while loop to end. And even if i closed the window the browser is crashing.

Comment: In Parent html/page
var myexecution = 1;
var callbackreceived = false;

console.log(myexecution);

//function to execute from child
function myFunc() {
  callbackreceived = true;
}


function myfunc(){
 var win = window.open("");
 win.onload = function() {
  win.RunParentFunction = myFunc;
 };
 do {
  console.log("pause");
 }
 while (callbackreceived === false);
 myexecution = myexecution + 1;
 console.log(myexecution);
}
In child page
var RunParentFunction = function() {};
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
 RunParentFunction(); 
}

Comment: My requirement is.. send some details to an web application (I cannot use ajax) which is an SAML authentication application (redirections will happen so cannot use ajax) and wait for its result and then continue my operation (some statements below window.open). I have no doubt that your code works.. Currently I am using the same (but using setInterval which check if window.closed). I was just curious to know if there is any other way. Thank you very much for your support.

Comment: I got the solution. We can use async await promise. For IE Support check https://gist.github.com/DejanBelic/d3b8a008049cd160941f391d326cdaab